# How To Align All Buttons In One Line On All Devices? (Without Changing Text)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a resource page on my blog which contains all the required resources needed for online businesses.

I want to make sure that all the buttons should appear in one line on all devices.

[image]

If you want to check actual page, here is the link: [Resource Page](https://pullthatmoney.com/resources/)

Comment: Try a min-height for that content wrap div if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more a simple CSS flexbox question and not anything to do with WordPress specifically.  Adding this CSS to your theme or customizer will align the buttons in the same place.

```
.thrv_wrapper.thrv-button {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```